# Use dyanamic json in PSTreeGraph

Tags: ios, json, graph, orgchart

I am trying to implement the organisation chart in my app. I searched allot than i found the PSTreeGraph(https://github.com/epreston/PSTreeGraph) which is completing my requirement but i am stuck in one point that example Mr.ED has given is very good but I am not getting how to customize it for my use.

My requirement is very simple I have dynamic json which I have to plot on graph (with some name, detail, image).

I have wasted 3 days for this customization please help me in this.

If any one can share sample code than it would be great.

I also want to share that there is one issue in which Mr.ED has explained how we can use json file for PSTreeGraph referral URL : https://github.com/epreston/PSTreeGraph/issues/9

Comment: Please post code here rather than relying on links.

Comment: I am using the same code from github